# NullReferenceException when using Event with timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task-parallel-library

When using a `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait()` with a timeout in a ASP.MVC context using tasks I get a NullReferenceException in the ASP framework that i can't catch.

Here is my code:

```
private static ManualResetEventSlim _event = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _event.Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)));
    await task;
    return View();
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(bool setImpersonationContext = {unknown})
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(bool setImpersonationContext = {unknown})
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.Util.ISyncContext.Enter()
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(System.Action action = {unknown})
System.Web.dll!<>c__DisplayClass9.AnonymousMethod(System.Threading.Tasks.Task _ = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext = {unknown}, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback = {unknown}, object state = {unknown}, bool preserveSyncCtx = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext = {unknown}, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback = {unknown}, object state = {unknown}, bool preserveSyncCtx = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution = {unknown})
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at [the sample in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873178#WHToTap) which has some simpler code to convert a wait handle to a task? (No timeout, but including that is trivial.) If the error still occurs with that code, at least it'll be simpler.

Comment: Is the controller action waiting for the (asynchronous) timeout to complete? I'm wondering if an `async` method is attempting to resume on a request context for a request that has already completed.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, the action is waiting.

Comment: @Jeroen: Tried it, no change.

Comment: Then the problem is definitely related to how ASP.NET manages thread contexts as this works without trouble in a regular environment (not a big leap of logic, I know :-)) Unfortunately, I know nothing about that. The only thing I can think of is to explicitly use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to not switch back to the current thread, but this is obviously no good if you need to do something with the request.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. Further tests suggest the problem is an ASP.Net problem. And it only occurs when using a timeout. Strange.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the new findings.

Comment: @MartinWalter responding to your edit, is this the full code one need to reproduce the issue? Did you set any ASP.NET timeout to shorter than 10sec?

Comment: @usr: Yes, that's all the code. I' didn't mess with ASP settings.